# Paypal Integration Django Rest Api/ Android Client

Tags: android, django, paypal, client, rest

i am trying to implement a Paypal payment system. I am working with a Django Server API and my client is an android Kotlin app. My question is, where is the best spot to implement the paypal integration.
Is it secure to implement it on the client side, because hackers could change the amount of money for example. But on the other hand how could I implement it server-side logically and the customer could use it on his mobile device.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make two routes on your django server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Or, look at the new Native Checkout SDK, which has Kotlin samples.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I an´m now working through the docs for a server side sdk implementation. Do you have a github repo with an example maybe. I am not 100 % sure in which apps and files i have to include all the stuff in my django app.